# How to validate against a different Mongoid collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid

**Background:**

We need to throw away existing data and import new data each day. The import takes ~15 min, and we don't want the site to be without data during that time. My coworker's solution is to import the new data into a temporary collection, and, once it's done importing, rename the temporary to the production collection name. We save the new data one record at a time, not in a bulk save (as the second related question does).

However, I want to know if an object I'm trying to save to the temporary collection fails uniqueness with another object in that collection (disregarding uniqueness with the production collection). Currently when I call `valid?` it validates against the production collection, not the temporary collection. I'd like to scope my validations to a particular collection. (As in, if I check uniqueness on `name` I only want to check against the records in a given collection.)

**Question:**

How can I pass a collection name through for use with `valid?`? Or is there another way to validate objects against a non-default collection?

**Related questions:**

- [Using collection-level operations in Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380874/using-collection-level-operations-in-mongoid)
- [Validating against a collection (array) in Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380741/rails-use-existing-model-validation-rules-against-a-collection-instead-of-the-d)